# How to save "current perspective" in code::blocks?

Tags: codeblocks, perspectives

Example: i'd like to always see "CPU Registers" and never see "Scripting Console".

Using Code::Blocks, how can i do this, regardless of the project i use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You realize the CPU register window won't show anything unless you're actually debugging right?

Anyway, to save a perspective in C::B, setup the IDE to the layout you want and just save it. In your case, you would do something like the follow:

- have the debug toolbar visible. Enable it by going
  to View->Toolbars->Debugger.
- display CPU window from debugger toolbar. Find 'Debugging
  windows'->'CPU Registers'.
- Hide the scripting console. Go to View->Script Console and uncheck.
- Set the layout to your preference and save. Go to View->Perspectives->Save current. Give it a name.

The next time you start C::B it'll use the last perspective you were on when you quit. So make sure you exit C::B with the new saved perspective.